# From camera calibration to picking up colored cubes with robot arm

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration, robotics, coordinate-transformation

I want to pick up colored cubes with a robot arm that I detect with a camera and OpenCV, in Python. I managed to detect the different colored cubes and I calibrated the camera with the checkerboard process.

**The setup:**

[image: Setup front]
[image: Setup top]

**Cube detection:**
[image: Cubes detected]

The problem is that I don't understand the rest of the process of getting the coordinates from the object with the camera and translating them to the robot arm for pick up.

**The following steps have been completed:**

1. Separating color boundaries with HSV and drawing bounding boxes. So I have the pixel x, y of the object.
2. Calibrating the camera resulting in the following camera matrix and distortion coefficients:

   Camera Matrix: [[1.42715609e+03 0.00000000e+00 9.13700651e+02]  [0.00000000e+00 1.43275509e+03 5.58917609e+02]  [0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00]]

   Distortion:[[ 0.03924722 -0.30622971  0.00124042 -0.00303094  0.49458539]]
3. Trying to figure out the next steps in the documentation of OpenCV

**The result**

I read through the API documentation on this page: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html

But with my skill level I can't seem the extract the practical steps to take, in order to attain my goal.

My questions:

1. How do I use the camera matrix and distortion coefficients to get coordinates of the object in the image frame?
2. How do I translate the coordinates on the image frame to the robot end-effector coordinates?
3. If I keep the camera on a fixed position. Does this mean I only have to do the calibration ones?

******* **edit:** *******

I went for a different approach. I managed to solve the rotation and translation between two coordinate systems through SVD. But I made an error in thinking I could use pixel coordinates to translate from the camera coordinate system to that of the robot. I think you need to translate the u, v values first.

**How can I translate the pixel uv to world coordinates, so that I can use the code below to get translation and rotation to robot arm?**

Here's my code:

```
#######################################################################
# Step 1: Input camera and world coordinates, and calculate centroids #
#######################################################################
print("")

# Camera and robot to world coordinates
Pc = np.matrix([[604,119,0],[473,351,0], [730,329,0]])
print("Camera points matrix: ")
print(Pc)
print("")

Pr = np.matrix([[177,-38,0],[264,-93,0], [258,4.7,0]])
print("Robot points matrix: ")
print(Pr)
print("")

# Calculate centroids
Cc = Pc.mean(axis=0)
Cr = Pr.mean(axis=0)

print("Centroid camera: ")
print(Cc)
print("")
print("Centroid robot: ")
print(Cr)
print("")

# Pc and Pr - centroids of Pc and Pr
Pc_minus_Cc = np.subtract(Pc, Cc)
print("Pc - centroidC: ")
print(Pc_minus_Cc)
print("")

Pr_minus_Cr = np.subtract(Pr, Cr)
print("Pr - centroidR: ")
print(Pr_minus_Cr)
print("")

############################################################################
# Step 2: Calculate H, perform SVD and get rotation and translation matrix #
############################################################################

# Get H
print("(Pr - centroidR) transposed: ")
print(Pr_minus_Cr.T)
print("")
H = np.matmul(Pc_minus_Cc, Pr_minus_Cr.T)
print("H: ")
print(H)
print("")

# Perform SVD
u, s, v = np.linalg.svd(H)
print("SVD result: ")
print("u: ")
print("")
print(u)
print("")
print("s: ")
print(s)
print("")
print("v: ")
print(v)
print("")

# Calculate rotation matrix
R = np.matmul(v,u.T)
print("Rotation matrix: ")
print(R)

# Calculate t
t = -R * Cc.T + Cr.T
print("t: ")
print(t)
```

Comment: The camera matrix is related to the camera per se (focal length, image size, etc) I suggest [this article](http://ksimek.github.io/2013/08/13/intrinsic/). So in other words, for question 3, If you have the same camera/resolution, the calibration (in this case the camera matrix) is the same. For question 1 and 2, you need depth, or know points which you can get the depth out of it. You can take a look to [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/19/find-distance-camera-objectmarker-using-python-opencv/) and [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/dc/d2c/tutorial_real_time_pose.html)

Comment: Thanks! I'm reading through it now.

Comment: Hi! I'm a bit further now, see my edit. Could you let me know if you can help me with the final step?

Answer (score 0):

to 1) you have already code which draws boxes around detected objects. So you have already coordinates in your matrix. If not you could do something like that.

```
        for c in contours:
        if cv2.contourArea(c) < self.min_area:
            continue
        # detected
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

and than x + w / 2 is your x in the matrix

to 2 ) you cannot directly you would need someorientation point so that the Arm 
would know where (x+y distance) starts your matrix in the world of the arm

to 3) calibartion depends always on your light conditions right ? so as long they don't change your calibartion should be fine. However it turns out the calibration is needed from time to time e.g. with usb cameras

Comment: to 1 > those are pixel x and y. These don't account for rotation, translation and scaling towards world coordinates. Nor are they usable for the robot arm to pick up the cubes. Any idea how I can do all the steps?

Comment: this will be hard  if you don't use any framwork. Did you look at ROS ? they have https://wiki.ros.org/move_arm which basically does exactly that

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! I'm a bit further now, see my edit. Could you let me know if you can help me with the final step?

Comment: no sorry, that all is a bit to complex for a forum help, you would need a translation map that is dedicated to your robot arm which I don't have. You could do something like putting a ruler cross in the middle of your screen matrix an work on the translation until a move is exactly e.g. one cm. See this very old document about it http://www.willowgarage.com/sites/default/files/calibration.pdf